# MSBI ISPAC file does not execute on double click

Tags: msbi

I  have VS 2017 SSDT 2017 and SQL Server 2017 . I have created the ISPAC setup of SSIS but when i double click on the setup file it does not execute and prompts me asking how to open the same.

I was watching the training videos of Questpond of MSBI in that trainer easily just clicked on the ISPAC setup and ran it .

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent windows version ISPAC file extension is not recognized. So that why it does not  not start on double clic and shows the open with dialog box.

So I would suggest to go through the integration services catalog menu as shown below.  This menu is available in SQL server management studio when you connect to the RDBMS. Right click on the projects of the folder name and click on deploy project menu.

[image: MSBI ISPAC ISSUES]

In the next screen  you can browse and pick up your ISPAC file and the deployment will start normally.

[image]

Disclaimer :- I am the author of the course.